# React: How can I add a second filter and filter through an array of objects, that are already being filtered once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects called `brands`, and I want to apply multiple filters to it, which are 'Connections' and 'Types'.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSmA9.png)

I would like the the first filter and second filter to work together, meaning whatever combination is chosen from each, the array is filtered accordingly and the correct results (objects) are showing on the page.

I already have a filter function and it works for the first filter (Connections). I have been trying to add more `if/else` statements to it to make the second filter work too, but it hasn't. I'm not sure where to go.

I'm trying to keep it down to having only one filter function if possible and this is what I've got so far:

```js
  const [filterValueConnection, setFilterValueConnection] = React.useState('all')
  const [filterValueType, setFilterValueType] = React.useState('allTypes')

  
const filteredBrands = (brands) => {

const connections = brands.filter(brand => {
  if (filterValueConnection === 'multipleConnections') {
    return brand.multipleConnections === true 
  } else if (filterValueConnection === 'singleConnection') {
    return brand.singleConnection === true
  } else {
    return filterValueConnection === 'all'
  }
})
console.log(connections)
return connections.filter(connection => {
  if (filterValueType === 'clothing') {
    return connection.clothing === true
  } else if (filterValueType === 'footwear') {
    return connection.footwear === true
  } else {
    return filterValueType === 'allTypes'
  }
})

return connections
}
```

And this is how I'm getting the data in jsx:

```js
{brands ? 
            filteredBrands(brands).map(brand => (
              <BrandCard 
                key={brand._id}
                name={brand.name}
                logo={brand.logo}
                clothing={brand.clothing}
                footwear={brand.footwear}
                brandId={brand._id} />
            ))
            :
            <p>...loading</p>
          }
```

Comment: Add `brands`, the output of `filteredBrands(brands)` to the question.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code that I can see, I suspect your data is not as you expect it to be

Comment: Hi @andymccullough The data is fine I believe as the first part of the filter works fine. Perhaps I didn't understand what you meant?

Comment: Hi @RameshReddy I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @EsinYil `console.log` `brands` and `filteredBrands(brands)` before returning the JSX and add it to your question

Comment: Why do you have two return statements?